# Proper way to use PDO/PHP to insert data into a preset database and table in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So, I've been using PDO/PHP to build a login/sign-up form for my website.  Now that I've managed to use PDO to connect and build a complete database and table that I want the data to go in.  I want to know what would the proper way to insert data into that table using the $_POST superglobal. Thanks.

Comment: Try [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: Use an `INSERT` query to insert data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, column3) VALUES  (:insert_value1, :insert_value2,:insert_value3";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':insert_value1', $_POST[value1]);
$stmt->bindParam(':insert_value2', $_POST[value2]);
$stmt->bindParam(':insert_value3', $_POST[value3]);
$stmt->execute();
```